# Splitting a string into multiple spans based on a set of overlapping ranges

Tags: c#, string, algorithm

I need to split a string into multiple substrings based on a set of range values, with each substring tagged with the set of applicable ranges. There should be no overlap in the resulting collection of substrings, and substrings that don't match any of the ranges in the set still need to be included in the results.

Currently I iterate across the string to find the matching ranges for each character, then loop through the result of that iteration to build each substring based on contiguous matching range sets. However, I'm certain that there is a much more efficient way of doing this.

The app this is for is written in C#, but textual descriptions of algorithms for solving this problem are also accepted.

### Example

Let the string be:

> Scelerisque suspendisse congue habitant scelerisque sociis placerat a himenaeos diam nunc vestibulum nec ultrices nisl himenaeos viverra mus hac.

Let the ranges be, specified as starting and ending indices (inclusive):

1. (12,50) - matches "suspendisse congue habitant scelerisque"
2. (24,29) - matches "congue"
3. (59,88) - matches "placerat a himenaeos diam nunc"
4. (80,103) - matches "diam nunc vestibulum nec"
5. (114,127) - matches "nisl himenaeos"

The result should be:

1. range (0,11), substring "Scelerisque ", matched ranges []
2. range (12,23), substring "suspendisse ", matched ranges [1]
3. range (24,29), substring "congue", matched ranges [1,2]
4. range (30,50), substring " habitant scelerisque", matched ranges [1]
5. range (51,58), substring " sociis ", matched ranges []
6. range (59,79), substring "placerat a himenaeos ", matched ranges [3]
7. range (80,88), substring "diam nunc", matched ranges [3,4]
8. range (89,103), substring " vestibulum nec", matched ranges [4]
9. range (104,113), substring " ultrices ", matched ranges []
10. range (114,127), substring "nisl himenaeos", matched ranges [5]
11. range (128,144), substring " viverra mus hac.", matched ranges []

### Further information

Ranges will never be zero-length. Results of the split operation should not include any zero-length substrings either.

Aside from simple overlapping, multiple ranges can have the same starting index or ending index. This is not demonstrated in the example above.

Comment: Is it ok that result doesn't contain *range (12, 49), substring "suspendisse congue habitant scelerisque", matched ranges [1]* ?

Comment: There should be no overlaps or gaps in the substrings produced. The existence of range 2 means that three substrings should be produced from range 1, being the substring from the start of range 1 to the start of range 2, the substring for range 2 (tagged for both ranges), and the substring from the end of range 2 to the end of range 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Split your ranges into events (index, type, range): 1. (12,50) => (12, start, 1) and (50, end, 1)
- Sort them
- Initialize an empty set of integers and currentIndex = 0
- Iterate each event
- If event is a start, push into results (currentIndex, event.index - 1), matches ranges = set.toArray(). Add event.range to set. Set currentIndex = event.index
- If event is a end, push into results (currentIndex, event.index), matches ranges = set.toArray(). Remove event.range from set. Set currentIndex = event.index + 1
- After all were iterated, add the missing result: (currentIndex, string.length), matches []

This works assuming events have unique indexes. Needs a bit of modification to handle things like [(12,50), (12,40), (15, 50)].

Comment: Yeah, it's very possible that two ranges might start at the same character index. With my hopelessly-naive solution that's not a problem, but in the case of your solution I suppose that I'd need to filter out any zero-length results.

Comment: @ChrisCharabaruk Yeah filtering out 0 length ranges is the easiest. To actually handle it though you need to change event structure to be (index, list of start ranges, list of end ranges) and add all/remove all from set when processing.

Answer (score 0):

This is my basic, worst-case implementation, with O(m*n) building `rangedChars` and then O(n log n) converting that to `substrings`.

Rather than use inclusive-end ranges, the code I've written myself works on start and length.

```cs
var text = "Scelerisque suspendisse congue habitant scelerisque sociis placerat a himenaeos diam nunc vestibulum nec ultrices nisl himenaeos viverra mus hac.";
var ranges = new Range[]
{
    new Range(12, 39),
    new Range(24, 6),
    new Range(59, 30),
    new Range(80, 24),
    new Range(114, 14)
};

var rangedChars = new RangedChar[text.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    rangedChars[i] = new RangedChar(i, text[i], ranges.Where(r => r.ContainsIndex(i)));

var substrings = new List<RangedString>();
for (int i = 0; i < rangedChars.Length; )
{
    var appliedRanges = rangedChars[i].Ranges;
    int j = i + 1;
    while (j < rangedChars.Length && appliedRanges.SequenceEqual(rangedChars[j].Ranges))
        j++;

    var substring = String.Join("", text.Substring(i, j - i));
    substrings.Add(new RangedString(i, substring, appliedRanges));

    i = j;
}

return substrings;

// supporting types

readonly struct Range
{
    public int Start { get; }
    public int Length { get; }
    public Range(int start, int end) { Start = start; End = end; }
    public bool ContainsIndex(int index) => index >= Start && index < (Start + Length);
}

public class RangedChar
{
    public int Index { get; }
    public char Character { get; }
    public IReadOnlyList<Range> Ranges { get; }
    public RangedChar(int index, char character, IEnumerable<Range> ranges)
    {
        Index = index;
        Character = character;
        Ranges = ranges.ToList();
    }
}

public class RangedString
{
    public int Start { get; }
    public string Text { get; }
    public IReadOnlyList<Range> Ranges { get; }
    public RangedString(int start, string text, IEnumerable<Range> ranges)
    {
        Start = start;
        Text = text;
        Ranges = ranges.ToList();
    }
}
```